# Road tripping the US from UK with 90 day visa waiver more than once a year?

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program

I'm currently on a road trip in the USA from the UK using the 90 day visa waiver program - I'm here for 87 days. Then I fly home, do some travelling around Europe etc. and want to fly back for approximately another 90 days about two months after I return home. From the US I'll possibly then be going on to New Zealand or Australia, if not home.

Does anyone know if this is okay?

Comment: Yes it's okay, but you're somewhat at the mercy of the CBP officer who admits you. If they think you're trying to live in the US, they can deny entry. After a two-month absence, that seems unlikely.

Comment: Expect a pretty rigorous grilling from the CBP. In Europe, there's a formal rule that you can't stay more than 90 days out of any 180; in the US, that's not a literal rule but it is a rule of thumb. They are likely to get quite twitchy about you basically being in the US for six months out of an eight-month period -- that does look quite a lot like you're trying to live in the US.

Comment: The main question they will have is how are you supporting yourself during all this time in the US, as you are not allowed to work. Be prepared to have evidence of funds matching your needs during your trip + your trip out of the US.